# Dedekind Cuts and Real Numbers

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

A Dedekind cut L is a nonempty proper subset of the rational numbers that:
(1) Has no maximal element
(2) for all a,b in the rational numbers a is in L and b < a implies that b is in L.

If $D$ is defined as the set of Dedekind cuts, and $L$ and $K$ and $J$ are all Dedekind cuts, how can I prove the following properties for Real numbers?

1. Addition and multiplication are commutative and associative for all real numbers.
2. $\forall L \in D, L + 0 = L$ and $L \cdot 1 = L$.
3. $\forall L \in D, L + (-L) = 0$.
4. $\forall L \in D-\{0\}$, there exists a $K \in D$ such that $LK = 1$.
5. $\forall L,K,J \in D, L(K+J) = L \cdot K + L \cdot J$.

I honestly just have no idea where to start.  It is not that I am trying to get my proofs completed by someone - I just need help understanding so as to start them.

Comment: What is the definition you're using for real addition/multiplication?

Comment: It would be better to focus on a single question, and write out the definition of addition and multiplication of cuts. Then show whatever you are able to deduce before getting stuck.

Comment: what are 0, 1 and {0}?

Comment: DId you post this question a few hours ago and then delete it?

Comment: To answer my own question, yes, you did post this question (minus the first paragraph and the last paragraph), then after a few hours you deleted it and posted the slightly improved question. The correct way to handle this is to _edit_ the original question. I think it's too late for you to fix this now, and probably not worth the trouble for a moderator to fix it, since the responses to the new question cover the deleted responses well enough. Just please be more careful next time.

Comment: @davidk yes, he certainly did. I had asked him to stop reposting this content last night before 12 EDT, when there were two versions up.

Comment: @markfrazier persistent deletion and reposting of the same question is considered gaming the system, and you are going to get in trouble for it if you don't stop. To all appearances, one doing this appears to be trying to force their question to the top of the list, and/or fishing for a spoonfed answer (since they are willing to obliterate partial answers and not improve the post.)

Comment: I see also we have what should be an acceptable answer (giving "help understanding so as to start" the proofs), posted minutes after the question. If it answered the question, it should have been accepted. If not, one can always leave a comment saying what is missing from the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You lacked to mention how addition and multiplication on cuts are defined.
Addition is simple: $A+B:=\{\,a+b\mid a\in A\land b\in B\,\}$. One readily shows that this is indead a cut if $A,B$ are cuts. Thankfully, this definition is so simple that commutativity of $+$ follows immediately from commutativity of $+$ in $\mathbb Q$ and from commutativity of $\land$:
$$B+A= \{\,b+a\mid b\in B\land a\in A\,\}=\{\,a+b\mid a\in A\land b\in B\,\}=A+B.$$
Associativity of cut addition follows similarly from the corresponding properties of rational addition and logical connectives.

You also didn't include the definition of cuts $0$ and $1$. In general, for any rational $q$, we can define a corresponding cut, by abuse of notation also called $q$, via $q:=\{\,x\in\mathbb Q\mid x<q\,\}$.
To show that $L+0=L$, you have to show two things: $L+0\subseteq L$ and $L\subseteq L+0$. Buth follow readily from the condition that if $b<a\in L$ then $b\in L$. I suggest you spell out the definitions and verify this.

You also didn't mention how you define $-L$. The naive approach might be $\{\,-x\mid x\in L\,\}$, but that is not a cut - it  goes "the wrong way". To correct the problem, one tries to define it as $\mathbb Q\setminus\{\,-x\mid x\in L\,\}$, which is ofte a cut, but *might* accidentally have a maximal element. *Only* once that problem is corrected and you have a proper definition, you can proceed to show $L+(-L)=0$. (An alternative definition of the additive inverse might be $-L:=\{\,x\mid \exists z>x\forall y\in L\colon z+y< 0\,\}$; in the end the exact definition does not matter as long as it shows once and for all that there *exists* an additive inverse)