# Prove that $\alpha+0^*=\alpha.$

Tags: real-analysis

I was studying real analysis. I recently got to know the definition of a *cut*. The definition goes as follows:

> A set of $\alpha$ of rational numbers is said to be a cut if : (i) $\alpha\neq \emptyset, \alpha\neq \Bbb Q$ (ii) if $p\in\alpha$ and $q\in \Bbb Q$ with $q<p$ then $q\in\alpha$ (iii) if $p\in \alpha$ then $\exists q\in\Bbb Q$ with $q>p$ such that $q\in\alpha.$  The condition (ii) shows that if $\alpha$ contains a rational number then it contains all rational number preceeding it. The third condition shows that the set has no largest rational. If $\alpha=\{x\in \Bbb Q: x<r \space \text{and}\space r\in\Bbb Q\}$ then $\alpha$ is a cut and we denote $\alpha=r^*.$ We define the addition of two cuts $\alpha,\beta$ as $\gamma=\{r\in\Bbb Q| r=p+q\space \text{where }\space p\in \alpha \space \text{and}\space q\in\beta \}$ then, $\gamma$ is a cut. Now, clearly, $\alpha+0^*=\alpha.$

However, I dont understand how are they concluding, $\alpha+0^*=\alpha$ ? It makes no sense at all. Actually, $0^*=\{x\in\Bbb Q| x<0\}$ and $$\alpha+0^*=\{p\in\Bbb Q: p=x+a, \space \text{such that }\space \forall x\in 0^* \space \text{and}\space a\in \alpha\}.$$ But how does $\alpha+0^*$ become equal to $\alpha$ ?

Comment: (iii) could be worded simpler: "if $p\in \alpha$ then $\exists q\in\alpha$ such that $q>p$".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dedekind Cuts and Real Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228143/dedekind-cuts-and-real-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\alpha+0^*=\{a+x:a\in\alpha\text{ and }x\in\Bbb Q_-\}$$
$$=\{b\in\Bbb Q:\exists a\in\alpha\quad b<a\}$$

- is contained in $\alpha$ by (ii);
- contains $\alpha$ by (iii) because for every $b\in\alpha,$ there exists some $a\in\alpha$ such that $a>b.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Actually, though I sonehow understood the reasoning for "contains $\alpha$ by (iii)" but can you please elaborate upon this ? It would be so much helpful 

Comment: I just did. See also my second comment above.